# Calling Facebook Graph API on PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, facebook-graph-api, pyspark

I'm kinda new with spark, and I'm using PySpark to run over a list of users I have that connected to my application using Facebook Login.

The cluster has Spark 2.3.1 installed. 5 instances+master, on each one I've installed "facebook-sdk" library.
When I run a single command, I get the response back from facebook GraphAPI, and I can use it to whatever I need.
The problem is when I use the GraphAPI commands inside a function, and try to run on it using mapPartitions.

This is my code:

```
import facebook
import pyspark
from pyspark import *
from pyspark.sql import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

def fb_func(rows):
    fields='id,first_name,middle_name,last_name,gender,birthday'
    ret = []
    for row in rows:
        token = row[6]
        id = row[7]
        graph = facebook.GraphAPI(access_token=token, version=3.0)
        user = graph.get_object(id=id, fields=fields)

        ret.append(str(id) + "," + str(token) + "," + str(user['first_name']) + "," + str(user['middle_name']) + "," + str(user['last_name']) + "," + str(user['gender']) + "," + str(user['birthday']))

    return ret

file = spark.read.parquet("s3://parquet-files/fb_data/*")
fb_file = file.repartition(5)

fb_schema = StructType([
    StructField('user_id', LongType(), True), 
    StructField('token', StringType(), True), 
    StructField('first_name', StringType(), True), 
    StructField('middle_name', StringType(), True), 
    StructField('last_name', StringType(), True), 
    StructField('gender', StringType(), True), 
    StructField('birthday', StringType(), True)
])

fb_rdd = fb_file.rdd\
    .mapPartitions(fb_func)\
    .toDF(fb_schema)\
    .repartition(2)\
    .collect()
```

This is the error I get back:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o98.collectToPython.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 12.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 12.0 (TID 29, ip-185-16-116-233.ec2.internal, executor 1): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1540215271155_0064/container_1540215271155_0064_01_000002/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 217, in main
    func, profiler, deserializer, serializer = read_command(pickleSer, infile)
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1540215271155_0064/container_1540215271155_0064_01_000002/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 59, in read_command
    command = serializer._read_with_length(file)
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1540215271155_0064/container_1540215271155_0064_01_000002/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 170, in _read_with_length
    return self.loads(obj)
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1540215271155_0064/container_1540215271155_0064_01_000002/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 562, in loads
    return pickle.loads(obj)
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1540215271155_0064/container_1540215271155_0064_01_000002/pyspark.zip/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 929, in subimport
    __import__(name)
ImportError: ('No module named facebook', <function subimport at 0x7feea89b26e0>, ('facebook',))
```

I made sure that FB library is installed on all instances, so I have no idea why I'm getting this error...
If anyone has any idea why, I'd really appreciate any help to come!

Comment: If you  _made sure that FB library is installed on all instances_ then your PySpark is probably not using the expected interpreter or path. Try logging both (including `PYSPARK_PYTHON`) form the `mapPartition` and compare with the expected values.

Comment: Looks like the Facebook SDK is not properly installed on each node. Try to ssh into each node and run the import command from python shell